# why does the peer certificate CN does not match the CN='35.246.68.234'?

Tags: php, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am new to php and i am trying to connect to gloudsql using ssl 
certificates. But it is giving me an error about the CN. what does it mean 
and what is missing in my code? My project name is `wiiboardtest` and my 
instance name is `personal`

```
$key = 'C:/Users/tasne/Downloads/client-key.pem';
        $cert = 'C:/Users/tas/Downloads/client-cert.pem';
        $ca = 'C:/Users/tas/Downloads/server-ca (1).pem';
        $con = mysqli_init();

        if(!$con){
            die("mysqli_init failed");
        }

        $trial = 
mysqli_ssl_set($con,$key,$cert,$ca,NULL,'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA');
        mysqli_options($con, 
 MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, false);



        $dbhost = '35.246.68.234';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'waffer';
        $database = 'personal';
        $port = '3306';
$conn=mysqli_real_connect($con,$dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$database,$port,
MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT );

        if(!$conn){
            die("connect error due 
                       to:".mysqli_connect_error());
        };
```

> mysqli_real_connect(): Peer certificate  CN=`wiiboardtest:personal' did not match expected CN=`35.246.68.234'

Comment: When using TLS, use hostnames, not IP addresses to connect. X.509 certificates for TLS typically uses hostnames and hence the match is made with that (yes, they can authenticate IP addresses too and it is heavily used in some field, but this is rare elsewhere and if you really have this need you then should already be proficient with TLS operations).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - your comment is correct in general, but does not apply to Google Cloud SQL in this use case. These are private SSL certificates for connections to Cloud SQL. Cloud SQL (normally) does not have DNS names only IP addresses. Here the problem is not the IP address, he was missing a function call argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your function arguments are not correct. `mysqli_real_connect` requires 8 parameters, you passed 7, which means that `flags` parameter is used for `socket`.

Change this line:

```
$conn=mysqli_real_connect($con,$dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$database,$port,MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);
```

To this:

```
$conn=mysqli_real_connect($con,$dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$database,$port,NULL,MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);
```